# Is single-line conditional rendering possible?

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-6.0

How to render conditional elements in Blazor like in React JSX?

For example in `React`:

```
export const LoginPage: FC = () => {
  // useState's
  // useEffect's

  return <div>{!loadingState ? usernameState : <Spin />}</div>; // <-- Goal
};
```

And I've tried in Blazor:

```
<div>
  You logged in AS:
  @if (_loading)
  {
    <Spin/>
  }
  else
  {
    @_userName
  }
</div>
```

is there any way how to write this in one line?

Comment: One could argue that this is ugly code both in React and Blazor

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the actual problem? The Blazor code is rendering fragments, not returning a value. Each branch is equivalent to `{...}`, not the expression inside the component.

Comment: Besides, the React way is to use components with different states, not ternary operators to display different representations. There's even a [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

> How to render conditional elements in Blazor like in React JSX?

You can, but there are other ways to solve the example you show.  Showing some form of visual control for loading is so common you can build a component control.

Here's a bare bones example:

`LoadingControl.razor`

```
@*@if (this.IsLoaded)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}
else
{
    <div class="loader"></div>
}*@

@_content

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

    private RenderFragment _loader => builder => builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"<div class='loader'></div>");

    private RenderFragment _content => this.IsLoaded ? ChildContent : _loader;
}
```

I've shown two ways you can render the content.

You then use it like this:

```
<div>
  You logged in AS:
<LoadingControl IsLoaded="!_isLoading">
    @_userName
</LoadingControl>
</div>
```

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Zeroed it out.  See https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Blazor-Components.html for some more info on components.  Benny1973 - I try add useful stuff to my personal github site.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div> You logged in AS: @if(_loading){ <Spin/> } else { @_userName } </div>
```

Amazing, right?

If you specifically want to use the ternary operator, then I'm not sure, I'd have to think on it for a bit.

Comment: "Amazing, right?" - sry, but - no)) the "one-line" question was to use the ternary operator which can return `ComponentBase` or `string` depending on condition.

Comment: Why is it important to you whether you use a ternary or an if. . . else?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan this answer works and does answer your question. If you don't like it you'll have to provide an explanation. `I want to use the ternary operator` isn't sufficient. In fact, the ternary operator doesn't even apply here. The code is rendering fragments, not returning a value.